# How to save data AFTER button click on binded ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` binded to an `ObservableCollection`. Whenever I press on a ListBox item, I can see the information on a right-sided panel that I designed. I did that by `Binding` the selected item to each `TextBox` like this:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxEditName" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxClients, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
```

Where `ListBoxClients` is my `ListBox` object containing the `ObservableCollection` data, and in this specific `TextBox` I'm showing its `Name`.

NOTE: That part is working fine. If I select another item in the list, it changes.

Now comes the tricky part:
Whenever I edit the `TextBox`,  the `ListBox` item is being updated at the same time. I want the `ListBox` item to change when I press a `Save button`, NOT BEFORE.

I tried with all the `Binding Modes`:

- OneWay
- OneWayToSource
- ....

But the same effect happens: when my `TextBox` looses focus, the `ListBox` item is changed. So...
**How can I fire the save event when I press the button and NOT BEFORE?**

My code behind:

```
    private void ButtonSaveChanges_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DtoCustomer selectedCustomer = (DtoCustomer) ListBoxClients.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedCustomer == null) return;

        BindingExpression b = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(ListBoxClients, ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
        b.UpdateSource();
    }
```

It's not working... What's wrong in my code behind? My `ListBox` is binded to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: If I understand, add UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit to your binding, and then call the UpdateSource method to update the source
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, it's that. But my BindingExpression is not working. Just looking what can be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with your `Binding`'s `UpdateSourceTrigger`: `Explicit` lets you update it only when needed.

Example for you::

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxEditName" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxClients, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

In code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            BindingExpression b = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(TextBoxEditName, TextBox.TextProperty);
            b.UpdateSource();
}
```

This way, the `Binding` will only be updated when you explicitly call `UpdateSource`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because is not working for me... I copy my code behind.

Comment: can you check my code behind? I understand what you mean, but my ObservableCollection is not being updated... Any idea?

Comment: Now that I think about this, the `Binding` to update should be the `TextBox`'s one. It's obviously this one firing the change and not the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource`. Let me edit my post